# Proving that $x-x^2$ is a contraction without mean value theorem

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I proved that $f:\mathbb [0,1]\to\mathbb [0,1]$ defined by
$f(x):=x-x^2$ is a contraction but not a strict contraction (Example 6.6.2. in Terrence Tao's Analysis II). In both cases I used mean value theorem (as seen below). I wonder if there is a way to do it by just manipulating the absolute values. I feel that the mean value theorem is way stronger than needed to solve this.

**Proof of contraction:** if $x,y\in[0,1]$ with $x<y$, there exists $x_0\in[x,y]$ such that
$$
d(f(x)-f(y))=|f'(x_0)|d(x,y)=|1-2x_0|d(x,y).
$$
Since $x_0\in[0,1]$ then $|1-2x_0|\le 1$. Therefore,
$$
d(f(x),f(y))=|1-2x_0|d(x,y)\le d(x,y)
$$

**Proof of not strict contraction:** Let $0<c<1$ be a constant and let us show that there exist $x,y\in [0,1]$ such that $d(f(x),f((y))>cd(x,y)$.

Let $x=0$ and $y=(1-c)/2\in[0,1/2]$. By the mean value theorem, there exists $x_0\in[x,y]$ such that
$$d(f(x)-f(y))=|f'(x_0)|d(x,y)=|1-2x_0|d(x,y).$$
Since $x_0<y=(1-c)/2$, then $c<1-2x_0$. Thus $|1-2x_0|>c$. Therefore,
$$d(f(x)-f(y))=|1-2x_0|d(x,y)>cd(x,y).$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, it's fairly straightforward.

Consider that $f(x) - f(y) = (x - x^2) - (y - y^2) = (x - y) - (x^2 - y^2) = (x - y) (1 - x - y)$.

Then in particular, we have $d(f(x), f(y)) = |x - y| |1 - x - y| = d(x, y) |1 - x - y|$.

Now we see that $-1 \leq 1 - x - y \leq 1$. In particular, the extremes are only achieved when $x = y \in \{0, 1\}$, so when $x \neq y$, we have $-1 < 1 - x - y < 1$. In this case, we see that $|1 - x - y| < 1$. Therefore, we see that when $x \neq y$, we have $d(f(x), f(y)) = d(x, y) |1 - x - y| < d(x, y)$.

Now suppose the map were a strict contraction. Then take some $c \in (0, 1)$ such that for all $x \neq y$, we have $d(f(x), f(y)) < c d(x, y)$.

Then let $k = \frac{1 + c}{2}$; then $0 < c < k < 1$. And we see that $d(f(1), f(k)) = d(1, k) |1 - 1 - k| = d(1, k) |k| = d(1, k) k > d(1, k) c > d(f(1), f(k))$. This is a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
$$f(x)-f(y) = (x-y)(1-(x+y)), $$
$$0 \le x+y \le 2.$$

Comment: Turn those into strict inequalities:  $x$ and $y$ can't both be $0$ or $1$.

Comment: @JosephCamacho I consider arbitrary $x,y \in [0,1]$. If we additionally assume $x \ne y$, we get in fact $0 < x+y < 2$.